# The component styled.div with the id of "sc-fEOsli" has been created dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am applying styles to my app.

The app works perfectly without styles.

When using the Page and Navigation elements from styled-components, I start seeing the error:

checkDynamicCreation.js:32 The component styled.div with the id of "sc-fEOsli" has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.

come up in the console everytime the user types into the input field

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

The app:

```
       import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Blog from "./components/Blog";
import blogService from "./services/blogs";
import loginService from "./services/login";
import Notification from "./components/Notification";
import ErrorNotification from "./components/ErrorNotification";
import BlogForm from "./components/BlogForm";
import Togglable from "./components/Togglable";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { setBlogs } from './reducers/blogReducer'
import User from './components/User'
import SingleBlog from './components/SingleBlog'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
import Blogs from './components/Blogs'
import Logout from './components/Logout'



import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes, Route, Link
} from "react-router-dom"


const Page = styled.div`
  padding: 1em;
  background: papayawhip;
`

const Navigation = styled.div`
  background: BurlyWood;
  padding: 1em;
`

const Footer = styled.div`
  background: Chocolate;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 1em;
`

const App = () => {
 /* const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]); */
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
  const [newAuthor, setNewAuthor] = useState("");
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState("");
  const [newUrl, setNewUrl] = useState("");
  const [failureMessage, setFailureMessage] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService
      .getAll().then(blogs => dispatch(setBlogs(blogs)))
  }, [dispatch])

  const blogs = useSelector(state => state)



  /*
  useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then((blogs) => setBlogs(blogs));
  }, []); */

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem("loggedBlogappUser");
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON);
      setUser(user);
      blogService.setToken(user.token);
    }
  }, []);

  const handleAuthorChange = (event) => {
    setNewAuthor(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleTitleChange = (event) => {
    setNewTitle(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleUrlChange = (event) => {
    setNewUrl(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const user = await loginService.login({
        username,
        password,
      });

      window.localStorage.setItem("loggedBlogappUser", JSON.stringify(user));
      blogService.setToken(user.token);
      setUser(user);
      setUsername("");
      setPassword("");
      setErrorMessage(`${user.name} is now logged in!`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage(null);
      }, 5000);
    } catch (exception) {
      setFailureMessage("Wrong username or password");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setFailureMessage(null);
      }, 5000);
      setErrorMessage("Wrong credentials");
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage(null);
      }, 5000);
    }
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    window.localStorage.removeItem("loggedBlogappUser");
  };


  const padding = {
    padding: 5
  }
  /* const createBlog = async () => {
    try {
      const blogObject = {
        author: newAuthor,
        title: newTitle,
        url: newUrl,
        likes: 0,
      };

      await blogService.create(blogObject);
      setBlogs(blogs.concat(blogObject));
      setNewTitle("");
      setNewAuthor("");
      setNewUrl("");
      setErrorMessage(`${blogObject.title} has been added!`);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setErrorMessage(null);
      }, 5000);
    } catch (exception) {
      setErrorMessage(`blog couldn't be added`);
    }
  };
 */
 /* const handleLike = (id) => {
    const blog = blogs.find((b) => b.id === id);
    const changedBlog = { ...blog, likes: blog.likes + 1 };

    blogService
      .update(id, changedBlog)
      .then((returnedBlog) => {
        setBlogs(blogs.map((blog) => (blog.id !== id ? blog : returnedBlog)));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(`the blog '${blog.content} was already deleted from the server`);
        setBlogs(blogs.filter((b) => b.id !== id));
      });
  }; */

/*  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const blog = blogs.find((b) => b.id === id);

    if (window.confirm(`are you sure you want to remove ${blog.title}`)) {
      blogService
        .remove(id)
        .then(setBlogs(blogs.filter((b) => b.id !== id)))
        .catch((error) => {
          alert(`${error}`);
        });
    } else {
      alert("deletion cancelled");
    }
  };
 */

  
  /* const arrayforSort = [...blogs] */


  if (!blogs) {
    return null
  }

  if (blogs.length > 1) 
  {
  return (
  
    <Router>
        <Page>
      <Navigation>
       <div>

         <Link style={padding} to="/">home</Link>
    
       
                <Link style={padding} to="/blogform">blogform</Link>
                <Link style={padding} to="/users">Users</Link>
       
      
        <Link style={padding} to="/login">Login</Link>
        
         
   

      </div>
</Navigation>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/blogform" element={<BlogForm  newAuthor={newAuthor}
          newTitle={newTitle}
          newUrl={newUrl}
          handleAuthorChange={handleAuthorChange}
          handleUrlChange={handleUrlChange}
          handleTitleChange={handleTitleChange}
          setErrorMessage={setErrorMessage}
          blogs={blogs}/>} />
        <Route path="/login" element={user === null ? (
        <LoginForm handleLogin={handleLogin}  setUsername={setUsername} setPassword={setPassword} username={username} password={password} />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <p>{user.name} logged-in</p>
          <Logout handleLogout={handleLogout} />
        </div>
      )} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Blogs blogs={blogs} />} />
        <Route path="/users" element={<User/>} />
      </Routes>

    <div>

      <Notification message={errorMessage} />
      <ErrorNotification message={failureMessage} />

    
      <Togglable buttonLabel="new blog">
        <BlogForm
          newAuthor={newAuthor}
          newTitle={newTitle}
          newUrl={newUrl}
          handleAuthorChange={handleAuthorChange}
          handleUrlChange={handleUrlChange}
          handleTitleChange={handleTitleChange}
          setErrorMessage={setErrorMessage}
          blogs={blogs}
        />
      </Togglable>
        
    </div>
    </Page>
    </Router>
  );
      } else {
        return (
          <SingleBlog blogs={blogs} setBlogs={setBlogs}/>
        )
      }
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Move your styled components outside of your App function component.

Comment: This did not work

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a warning because you are defining your styled components within another component. If you hoist your styled components outside of your `App` component, this will remove the warning.

Here is a reproduction of the warning:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const ThisIsFine = styled.div``;

export default function App() {
  const ThisIsNotFine = styled.div``; // Moving this line outside of App removes the warning
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThisIsFine>Fine</ThisIsFine>
      <ThisIsNotFine>Not fine</ThisIsNotFine>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-swanson-0xud1q

Comment: I tried this and I am still getting the warning - all the styled components are now defined outside the App component and still the same result.

Comment: Can you update your original post with your updated code?

Comment: Code has now been updated

Comment: I have a feeling that the issue lies outside of this file. Do you have another file called `checkDynamicCreation.js`?

Comment: Closest I have is checkDynamicCreation.d.ts which says this => export declare const checkDynamicCreation: (displayName: string, componentId?: string | undefined) => void;
//# sourceMappingURL=checkDynamicCreation.d.ts.map